# Calculator in MFC dialog based

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, calculator

I am trying to create a calculator using **MFC dialog based** in visual studio 2010.So this is my code to show up on the calculator screen when I press button`1`.So if I press `1` once it should display `1` and if I press 1 three times it should display `111`.

```
void CCalculatorDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CString t;
    num1=(num1*10)+1;
    int n=num1;
    t.Format(_T("%d"),n);
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1,t);
}
```

My question is if I omit `int n=num1` and used `t.Format(_T("%d"),num1);` line this doesn't work.Is it because when converting `num1` to String does `num1` get converted to String.I thought the converted String value of `num1` would get stored in `CString t`, and `num1` would stay as `int`.

Also with this code if I keep on pressing `1` it works correctly until I press it for about 11 times.After that it displays `-2147483648` instead of `111111111111`.Why is this,Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this.I am completely new to MFC

Comment: Maybe you need a 64 bit integer or limit the # of digits if you are going to do 32 bit calculations. Although even with a __int64 there will be a limit. My point is `111111111111` is too big to fit in a 32 bit integer.

Comment: What is the type of num1? To be used with the "%d" format it must be an int.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP num1 is of type double.Now I change it to` %g` and now I can remove `int n=num1`.But still after pressing `1` for several times it displays `1.22211e+006`

Comment: @drescherjm : how can I num1 is double and in edit_box it takes input as Sting right? That is where the value is displayed .So with double and string can't I write more than 10 digits

Comment: I would leave the input as a string, so when they press the 1 key, just append a `1` digit to the string being displayed. Then, when they press an operation key (+, -, *, /, etc.) read the string and convert it to a number.

Comment: @JerryCoffin keeping the input as String solved the problem .Thanks